# adding logo on image is increasing size too much

Tags: c#, .net

I am adding logo on user given image. My User uploaded image size is 52KB and logo image size is 2KB. But when it final saved as new image its size become 162KB. Can anybody please help in optimizing its size.

Below is code, i am using:

```
public static string UploadAdPhoto(HttpContext cont,HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload, string AdId, string newfileName)
    {
        string path = cont.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/AdImages/" + AdId);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        string extension = ".jpeg";
        newfileName = newfileName + extension;
        string fileName = Path.Combine(cont.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/TempImages/"), newfileName);



        fileUpload.SaveAs(fileName);
        //
        Bitmap baseImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileName);
        //if (baseImage.Width > 720 || baseImage.Height > 540)
        //{
        //    fileName = resizeImageAndSave(fileName, baseImage.Width, baseImage.Height);
        //    baseImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileName);
        //}
        //Bitmap overlayImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/small_logo.png"));
        Bitmap overlayImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(cont.Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/logo-signature.png"));
        Bitmap finalImage = new Bitmap(baseImage, baseImage.Width, baseImage.Height);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage);
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(overlayImage,0,0, 20, 20);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =  System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
        ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        finalImage.Save(path + "/" + newfileName, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        baseImage.Dispose();
        finalImage.Dispose();
        return "~/Resources/AdImages/" + AdId + "/" + newfileName;
    }
```

Comment: Not familiar with working with images via code, but is it because you are doing this: `graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;`?  Does changing this impact the size of the resultant file?

Comment: No it does not make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to resize it?

```
        private void ResizeImage()
        {
            int iQuality = 70; //define your image quality
            string tempFileName;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                tempFileName = "resizedImage.jpg";

                long lengthInk = 0;
                do
                {
                    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    encoder.QualityLevel = iQuality;
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

                    using (var stream1 = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        encoder.Save(stream1);
                    }

                    FileInfo fInf = new FileInfo(tempFileName);
                    lengthInk = fInf.Length;
                    iQuality = iQuality - 5; //quality will continue to decrease by 5 until you reach the image size you want
                } while (lengthInk > 4028); //specify the maximum image size you want to have, for example 4028 for 4KB
            }
        }
```

You need to change the encoder quality level and the size as you wish.

Comment: I have removed jpeg encoder and saved image simply by giving it extension.. it worked. Thank you, your last line is helpful.